# how to close the app after user deactivate the account?

Tags: java, android

in my app i have to create deactivation code this is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getApplicationContext();
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manage_account);


        TextView deleteAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delete_account);
        deleteAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         // while clicking Delete My Account this method is called

           @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManageAccount.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Deactivate");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you really want to deactivate your account?");
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //while clicking YES button isDelete is stored as 1 in database
                        userMO.setIsDelete(1);
                        del();
                         new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateUser(userMO, context);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                        dbHelper.updateRingeeUser(1, userMO.getRingeeUserId(), userMO);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });

    }
```

after clicking   Manage Account--> Delete My Account--> YES/NO  Here  if user clicks YES button IsDelete will be stored as 1(user disabled in database) in database here inaddition i have to close that app and have to bring normal home page of the mobile 
any one can help me??

Comment: You want to restart the app when yes is clicked?

Comment: here app is deactivated after clicking yes button but after clicking that the app should be closed (that app window should not be shown after clicking yes)

Comment: try this: 
Toast.make...
MainActivity.this.finish();

Comment: thank you for your response

Comment: in this code what do you declare for MainActivity??

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should close the App after deactivating the acoount, but return the user to your Login screen:

```
Intent reLoginIntent = new Intent(context, Login.class);

reLoginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

startActivity(reLoginIntent);

finish();
```

If you just want to close the Activity, just use:

```
finish();
```

Comment: but where i have to add finish();

Comment: It depends on your needs, you should put it where and when you want the Activity to finish.

I think you have a wrong assumption in your code, because you use AsyncTask and then Toast when actually the operation isn't necessarily finished at that point.

Comment: thank you so much, i tried the first code you had given it is working perfectly

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Can you mark the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: i just added your code(first one) after the toast run(successfully deactivated")and called login activity from my project as you told